# Javascript: How to retrieve the JSON object in Data Attribute Without Parse

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, html

I am getting some data in the Data Attribute In HTML5 as :

```
<div id="dataAttribute" data-select="{"firstname":"Jesper","surname":"Aaberg","phone":["555-0100","555-0120"]}"></div>
```

And I am retrieving this object in the JS as :

```
var elem = document.getElementById("dataAttribute");
varObject = elem.dataSets.select;
```

But Here I am getting the data as the String. To change the data in to an Object I am prasing the data. **Which I want to Avoid.**

Is there any way to save the data in data attribute to a JS variabled without using the parse?

Comment: You want just in JS ? in jQuery it's return in object and not in string

Comment: @OriEng Hi, Actually we are not using Jquery in our Project hence we have to get it out in the Javascript. And in the datasets it is returning the string.

Comment: You can't store objects in HTML like this. Strings only -- what's wrong with parsing?